# Is it possible to disable drag and drop for specific cell in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I'm trying to drag and drop cells in my `Jtable`. It works but now I would like to know is it possible to disable drag and drop only for the first cell for example because I don't want this cell to be modified?

Here is the code

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
public Test() {
    setSize(500, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 5, 5));

    Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { "00", "10", null }, { "01", "11", null }, { "02", "20", null } };
    String[] name = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, name);
    JTable jt = new JTable(model);
    pan.add(jt);

    jt.setRowHeight(24);
    jt.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);

    jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    jt.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jt.setDragEnabled(true);
    jt.setDropMode(DropMode.USE_SELECTION);
    jt.setTransferHandler(new MyTransferHandlerT());

    setContentPane(pan);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}
}
```

and the code for `TransferHandler`

```
public class MyTransferHandlerT extends TransferHandler {

 private JTable table;
 private DefaultTableModel model;
 private int rowIndex;
 private int colIndex;

@Override
public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
    return MOVE;
}

@Override
protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent source) {

    table= (JTable)source;
    model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
    colIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();


    model.getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex);

    String value = (String)model.getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex);
    Transferable t = new StringSelection(value);
    return t;
}

@Override
protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {

    table= (JTable)source;
    model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
    colIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();

    model.setValueAt("", rowIndex, colIndex);
}

@Override
public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
    if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {

    table = (JTable) support.getComponent();
    Object data= null;
    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
    int col = table.getSelectedColumn();



    try {
        data = (Object) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
        System.out.println("unsupported Flavor Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    model.setValueAt(data, row, col);
    model.fireTableStructureChanged();
    return false;
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try to return null in method `createTransferable(JComponent)` when the cell should not be dragged.

Comment: I try to add this: if (model.getValueAt(0,0)=="00") {return null} in createTransferable but it does't work. Please can you show how you will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model.setValueAt(data, row, col);
//model.fireTableStructureChanged();
```

Do not invoke the fireTableStructureChanged() method directly. That is the responsibility of the TableModel.

> is it possible to disable drag and drop only for the first cell

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Location Sensitive Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/locsensitivedrop.html). It has an example that will disable drop on the first column.

Comment: Yeah thanks it's work for disable dropping, but not for dragging. So must write some extra code.